format_datetime filter is not displaying date in French
I am trying to display a date in French using Twig filter format_datetime. For instance, this code:
'2024-05-05 23:39:12'|format_datetime(locale='fr',pattern="EEEE dd MMMM YYYY") should display Dimanche 05 Mai 2024 but its displaying Sunday 05 May 2024 instead.
My setup :

Symfony 6.4
"twig/extra-bundle": "^3.9"
"twig/intl-extra": "^3.9"
In docker, I am using: php:8.3-fpm-alpine, docker-php-ext-configure intl, docker-php-ext-install intl
default locale is set to 'fr'

I don't know what I am missing here.
EDIT
It works with PHP 8.1

It's your timezone, set false.
you can try like this in your twig file :
{{ '2024-05-05 23:39:12'|format_datetime( pattern="EEEE dd MMMM YYYY", locale='fr', timezone=false) }}

Result :  dimanche 05 mai 2024
